# Problems with the Droitwich transmitter

Tags: transmitter

Does anybody know what is up with the BBC transmitter at Droitwich in the UK, specifically the Radio 4 Longwave broadcast on 198kHz?

It's been reporting intermittent faults for a while, and was off air for long periods in the last few days. It's on air again now and showing no fault on the [BBC status website](https://www.bbc.co.uk/reception/check-for-transmitter-faults/), but the frequency stability seems to be quite poor compared to how solid it used to be.

Does anyone have any insight into the problems, or any measurements of frequency stability before and after the fault developed?